# JavaScript click a button by name from chrome console

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to click programmatically a button from a web page using chrome console.

(UPDATED)The code of the button looks like this :

```
<FORM METHOD=GET ACTION="/xxx/yyy/kkk.jsp" >
    <INPUT type="hidden" name="page" value="721">
    <INPUT type="hidden" name="reqType" value="ReprintO">
    <INPUT type="hidden" name="title" value="Reprint Label">
    <INPUT type="hidden" name="system" value="reprint">
    <td align=right width=25%><input type=submit value='>' name=BTN_CHOICE5/>
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;Reprint Label
</form>
```

There are a couple more buttons on the page that have `value= '>'`, so I guess I need to click it using name. I tried
`document.querySelector('input[name="BTN_CHOICE4"]').click();` and it didn't work. How do I click this button using JS?

Comment: your html snippet does not appear to be valid...

Comment: You should wrap your attributes values in double quotes. `<input type="submit" value=">" name="BTN_CHOICE4" />`

Comment: I think you can't for security reasons. But then again, the click event should be linked in some cases to a function you could call.

Comment: @Fabricator: I've just updated it with a source for the button

Answer (score 9):

If you have ID attribute you can use

```
$('#btnId').click();
```

Or If you want to go by name, you can use

```
$('[name="someName"]').click();
```

But it would be good if you use by Id not by name as if multiple controls have same name attribute and value, then all those controls click event will be invoked.

Comment: I don't have an ID. And it needs to be a JS, not jQuery

Comment: This approach works if you replace `$` with vanilla JavaScript's `document.querySelector` or another call which will get the `Element` you're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this

```js
document.getElementsByName("BTN_CHOICE5")[0].click()
```

```html
<FORM METHOD=GET ACTION="/xxx/yyy/kkk.jsp" >
    <INPUT type="hidden" name="page" value="721"/>
    <INPUT type="hidden" name="reqType" value="ReprintO"/>
    <INPUT type="hidden" name="title" value="Reprint Label"/>
    <INPUT type="hidden" name="system" value="reprint"/>
    <td align=right width=25%><input type=submit value='>' name=BTN_CHOICE5 onclick="alert('test')"/></td>
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;Reprint Label</td>
</FORM>
```

Answer (score 3):

Like Rakesh said,
`$('#btnId').click();`
works.

Easy mode, though, is to right click the element in the browser, click inspect (or find it in the elements selector, then select it), then simply fire the event on the selected element:

```
$0.click();
```

Answer (score 2):

regarding the following HTML:

```
<input type=submit value='>' name=BTN_CHOICE5/>
```

you should be aware of:

1. the character `>` should be entity encoded `&gt;`
2. when an attribute doesn't use quotes (`"` or `'`) to delimit its value, all characters until the first space or `>` are interpreted as the value. In your case this means that `name=BTN_CHOICE5/>` translates to `name="BTN_CJOICE5/">`.

---

If the exercise of clicking the button is meant to submit the `<form>`, you should know that synthetic events like [`.click()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) do not trigger default actions. May I suggest [submitting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) the form instead?

```
document.querySelector('form').submit()
```

Comment: Thanks. The website was not written by me, I'm just trying to make a script that will perform a certain task on this website, and this button needs to be clicked(submitted).