# how to click a button in a webpage from chrome console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

I used

**Method 1:**
`$("button").click();`
**Result:** `Cannot read property 'click' of null`

**Method 2:**
`$("button").trigger("click");`
**Result:** `Cannot read property 'trigger' of null`

Comment: Does the button have `id` value? Does the web page contain `jquery` file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37667139/javascript-click-a-button-by-name-from-chrome-console . If you mean it, of course. Your question is not complete.

Comment: In chrome console, you can use `$0` to refer the selected element

Comment: Try `$("button")[0].click();`

Comment: var intervalID; 
$('.button').click(function(){ 
 intervalID = setInterval(function(){
    $("._njrw0").click();
},3000);
});

when i run this code in chrome console i got  "cannot read property click of null"

Comment: but wehn i run $("._njrw0").click(); it is triggering. But i need to trigger every 3 seconds

Answer (score 2):

solution if an ID and jQuery not available:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].click();
```

Answer (score 1):

If your page doesn't reference jQuery, you can simply find the element by its ID using javascript and attach click event to it as follows:

```
document.getElementById('mainbar').addEventListener("click", function() 
{
    console.log('main bar clicked');
});

Using jQuery:

$('#buttonid').click();
```